# Programmatically Check MySQL's Option Values (key_buffer_size, innodb_buffer_pool_size, etc.)

Tags: php, mysql, configuration

Is it possible to programmatically (via. the SQL interface, a CLI tool, etc) check the values of options that are normally set in a MySQL server's `my.cnf` file?

I have a suspicion that the server I'm using is reading the incorrect configuration file, and I'd like to be able to check what the values are actually set to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can access them via `SELECT` statements since they are exposed as [global system variables.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-system-variables.html)

```sql
SELECT @@key_buffer_size;
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;

-- With a column alias you can use when fetching an associative array in PHP
mysql> SELECT @@key_buffer_size as keybufsize;
+------------+
| keybufsize |
+------------+
|    8388608 |
+------------+
```

You can, obviously, do this via PHP or the CLI, or whatever.

Comment: Just what I couldn't find, thanks! (also, "show global variables;" is useful)

Answer (score 0):

is the keybufsize in bit 8388608 equal to 1MegaByte,what the difference between @@key_buffer_size and @@innodb_buffer_pool_size

Comment: is this a question